# How Pango Text Markup Language is used with GTK box ? other than gtk label

Tags: c, gtk

In Book "Foundations of GTK+" . It is written that The Pango Text Markup Language allows you to change the styles of text with XML tags in some widgets, such as GtkLabel. I was wondering how can i change the background color of Gtk Box ?? Can Pango Text  Markup Language be used with Gtk Box

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be. See e.g. [this description](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.22/pango-markup-language.html). I suggest you 1) install Devhelp; 2) use something else than C for learning GTK+, e.g. Python. I'm not implying you shouldn't write in C, just for quick prototyping etc. it is too cumbersome.

Here is how you do it:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

box = Gtk.Box ()
box.add (Gtk.Label ('some test label'))

# You need a wrapping Gtk.EventBox because Gtk.Box lacks a GDK window:
wrapper = Gtk.EventBox ()
wrapper.add (box)
wrapper.override_background_color (Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA (1, 1, 0.5))

window = Gtk.Window ()
window.add (wrapper)

window.connect ('destroy', lambda *x: Gtk.main_quit ())

window.show_all ()
Gtk.main ()
```